# No console output using Keras model.fit() function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm following [this tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/) to perform time series classifications using Transformers with Keras and TensorFlow. I'm using Windows 10 and the PyDev Eclipse plugin. Unfortunately, my program stops and the console output is completely blank every time I run the following code:

```
n_classes = len(np.unique(y_train))
input_shape = np.array(x_trainScaled).shape[0:]

model = build_model(n_classes,input_shape,head_size=256,num_heads=4,ff_dim=4,num_transformer_blocks=4,mlp_units=[128],mlp_dropout=0.4,dropout=0.25)

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"])
print(model.summary())

callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=100, restore_best_weights=True)]

model.fit(x_trainScaled,y_train,validation_split=0.2,epochs=200,batch_size=64,callbacks=callbacks)

pathToModel = 'my/path/to/model/'
model.save(pathToModel)
```

Even previous warnings or print statements are completely erased and I have no idea what's going on. If I comment the model.fit(...) statement out, the program terminates and crashes with an error message resulting from a model.predict(...) call.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to transform the input data and labels to numpy arrays first. Thus, calling the fit function as follows:

```
model.fit(np.array(x_trainScaled),np.array(y_train),validation_split=0.2,epochs=200,batch_size=64,callbacks=callbacks)
```

worked perfectly fine for me, as opposed to:

```
model.fit(x_trainScaled,y_train,validation_split=0.2,epochs=200,batch_size=64,callbacks=callbacks)
```